# xcode 3.2.3 installation failed on Mac 10.6.3

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard

First I have install Mac 10.6.3 on my system now I want to install xcode 3.2.3 .But I get error as "An unknown installation error occured. The installer encountered an error that caused installation to failed."
Please Help me with this issue.

Comment: Not proper place to ask such question. Please ask in superuser.com

Comment: I had the same problem and realy the solution almand said worked for me too. I only change the system date to 1/1/2012. Thank almand. In this other post (http://superuser.com/questions/410573/cant-install-xcode-on-os-x-snow-leopard), there other solutions but i do not try because my problem already was solved. Thank very much to all people that help in this website with question and answer. Excuse my english.

Comment: Change your date to 1/1/2012 as almand said. It worked for me too!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

change your system date to 1/1/2012.

then try to install... it works for me

Comment: Fixed it for me... Don't see why this causes the problem. Nice error for my first use of the Mac OS

Comment: This is a crazy fix, but it worked for me as well. Thanks! Spent the last day downloading different XCode packages to see which ones worked.

Comment: Worked for me too. Would love to have an explanation! o_O

Comment: Strangest fix I've ever found on here.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2384700?start=15&tstart=0):

> Either make a new Admin user & try that account, or Software Update...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error stems from an expired certificate covering the iOS portion of the package. I assume you only need 3.2.6 to build universal binaries that support older PPC as well as Intel Macs right? That being the case, you can simply decline the second licence agreement covering iOS. The installer should then proceed to install only the Mac-related tools and SDKs.

Update: I see you were referring to 3.2.3 while I was referring to 3.2.6. I am not certain the installer works the same way, but imagine you would want 3.2.6 anyway?